# Is it possible to tell grunt-uglify to minimize JS code that is embedded in html source?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-uglify

I haven't found anything that could help me. I need to minimize JavaScript code that is embedded in the html files inside tags . How can I do that?

Something like that returns obvious error:

```
    uglify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.resources %>/views/{,*/}{,*/}{,*/}*.phtml']
            }
        }
    }
```

I know it's not pretty solution to keep lot of JavaScript code in html, but I really need.

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

IMO it does not work.

I don't know about your workflow, but it might be possible to place the content of the script tags into separate js files and use a grunt-plugin (or anything else) to inject the minified version into your templates.